# Memtable understanding

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I have some questions about cassandra memtable. I'll be grateful for the help.

Facts about memtable:

1) placed in RAM;

2) per-ColumnFamily structure;

3) multiple memtables may exist for a single column family;

Questions:

1) When additional memtable for column family are created? What condition is need? I assume that additional memtables are created after creation additional commit log file. This is true?

2) What occurs after reaching commit log size threshold? I assume that will start placing memtables to queue; after queue filling will start flushing memtable to sstable and after this the older commit log (on hdd) and corresponding memtable**s** (in ram) are removed. In this case some part of memtable memory will be alway empty and commit log always will be filled up to 90-100%?

3) What occurs when the memtable size threshold is reached? Like previous case will start flushing to sstable? Some part of commit log also will be always empty and memtable memory will be filled up to 90-100%?

4) About memtable_allocation_type:
in official recources - *"offheap_buffers moves the cell name and value to DirectBuffer objects. This has the lowest impact on reads — the values are still “live” Java buffers — but only reduces heap significantly when you are storing large strings or blobs."*. What does DirectBuffer mean? It is placed in java heap? Can you give links to websites with information about it?

thank you very much!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. For a given Column Family there is usually a single Memtable in memory except during special circumstances like repair process or pending flushes.
2. When the Commit Log is full, a flush is triggered: the Memtable is written to disk as a SSTable, then the Memtable is cleared and the Commit Log is recycled. A new cycle starts with an empty Commit Log/Memtable
3. When Memtable exceed a given size, a flush is triggered like above.
4. Usually Memtable is kept in Java heap memory by default. As of [Cassandra 2.1, Memtable can be stored outside the Java Heap](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/off-heap-memtables-in-Cassandra-2-1) to alleviate GC pressure. However this setting is an optimisation for some special case. Cassandra can store data outside the Java heap using JNA, this means this data is not eligible to garbage collection because it is not known of the JVM. However the Java objects must be transformed to be stored/retrieved in/from it. This is why these Java objects are not considered as "alive".

I advise you to watch https://academy.datastax.com/courses/learning-cassandra-write-path

Comment: Thanks! But in some articles and books exist the different information. Where true?

1) This is quote from book "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide" by Eben Hewitt: "This flushing is a nonblocking operation; multiple memtables may exist for a single column family, one current and the rest waiting to be flushed".

Comment: 2) Ok. Why do i need memtable_flush_queue_size parameter? By default it is equal 4. 4 means the count of column families. 
The quote from oficial documentation: "memtable_flush_queue_size (Default: 4) The number of full memtables to allow pending flush (memtables waiting for a write thread)". What does "full memtable" mean? If i have 3 column families at my keyspace - i will have no more than 3 memtable in ram?

3) Like above.

4) I don't know what is DirectBuffer. It located out of native Cassandra memory? Assume no. Then why we can see description "the values are still “live” Java buffers"?

Comment: This queue size is here because Cassandra as a SEDA architecture with working queues and all tasks are executed through thoses queues. This allows to control how much work is done concurrently. Usually 3 column families means 3 memtables. If flush takes time (loaded node) there may some pending memtables but it's not the nominal case. A DirectBuffer is memory area allocated directly using JNA (probably using malloc), it can not can not contain "live" Java objects, they must be serialized. Yet this memory is not managed by the JVM hence ignored by GC.

Comment: Beware the book "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide" is a bit old and some information is not up to date for recent Cassandra versions.

Comment: I want to clarify: after flushing will be removed all commit log files and all memtables and will be created new?

Comment: Can i ask the last question?
about memtable_flush_queue_size parameter: in manual exist recommendation "At a minimum, set to the maximum number of indexes created on a single table." Why indexes in a single table if this parameter sets maximum of memtable in queue?

Comment: During, flush Commit log files are not entirely re-created, the files are recycled. I don't know about Memtables. About indexes, each secondary index is stored as a kind of secondary Memtable (same data sorted differently) for the same Column family. The rule you quoted is here to ensure that main data and Indexes are written altogether. Using indexes is not recommended though and should be limited to special cases. Again I don't consider indexes to be the nominal scenario of flush. Having 3 indexes on a table seems like a poor idea.

Comment: I advise you the "Cassandra High Availability Progressing" book by Robbie Strickland.